# Prevent IntelliJ from compiling src-Classes when Unit-Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have the following Project Structure

```
/
   src/  # src-files for the app
    org.mayapp.main.Main/
 test/ # unit-tests
    org.myapp.test.main.MainTestSuite/
```

When I want to run my Unit-Tests, e.g. `org.myapp.test.main.MainTestSuite`, IntelliJ always tries to compile **all** the packages in the whole project.

I want to prevent this, because I am currently developing on a part of my app and still want to run the Unit-Tests on other parts of the app.

Is there a way to prevent IntelliJ from compiling the whole project before running the Unit-Tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run a test in IntelliJ you'll see it adds a run target for that test, see Run -> Edit Configurations under the JUnit section.

If you look at the run target for the test you'll see there's a *Before Launch* section that by default has *Make* selected.  If you unselect *Make* IntelliJ won't make/compile before the test is run.

Remember to save the run target as IntelliJ creates new ones as you run different tests.

Comment: After you remove *Make* click the plus sign, and you will want to select *Make no error checks* that way the dependencies will still be made but errors will not fail your build.